Change routes when child component activate
I want to do a login page with password reset page. In the page, only a tiny part of the page will change when i click on "reset password" so the view will be like this :
Login page:
<div class="container">
   <div *ngIf="route is login">
      <login-component></login-component>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="route is password forget">
      <password-forget-component></password-forget-component>
   </div>
</div>

When i click on password forgot button, i want the url to change from "/login" to "/login/forgot-password" for example. But it's in the same component and i don't know how to do this...
I think that in the component.ts i have to listen to ActivatedRoute, check if the route is /login/forgot-password, and if so make the state like this.state = 'password-forgot' (and if route is /login the state would be this.state = 'login'), but it's juste an intuition.
If you have better way of doing that also it would be nice thank you
bonus : if i can make the change of views in a transition animation !

In this case, I would use a router-outlet and rely on Angular routing.
LoginPageComponent - lets assume that this component contains all the common parts that won't change. It also has a router outlet for the part that does.
<div class="container">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

// in routing config

[
  // Other routes
  //... 
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'forgot-password',
        component: PasswordForgetComponent
      },
    ]
  }
]

This assumes that you don't have another router-outlet on the same level.
If you do, you'll likely need to use named router outlets.
Hope that helps :)

That's the ideal solution to his problem - @tebereth

thank you very much ! I will test this at work tomorrow and let you know. Before finishing my day on friday evening i found something that i thought could work but i didn't have the time to test it, and you just mentionned it : named router outlet. Because as you said there is another router outlet on the same level. My first tests weren't very conclusive.. I'll also dig into that
